# marking present and absent using php by reading names from a txt file

Tags: php, html

I have made a php file in which I am marking present and absent by reading the names given in "attendance.txt" file. How can I do this?
It is giving me wrong answer.
I have applied php in the  tag

```
<html>


<head>
<style>
table,th,td
{
border:1px solid black;
border-collapse:collapse;
}
th,td
{
padding:5px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body >



<div id="container" style="width:1250px">

<div id="header" style="background-color:#FFA500;">
<h1 style="margin-bottom:0;text-align:center;">WEBKIOSK ATTENDANCE</h1></div>

<div id="menu" style="background-color:#FFD700;height:500px;width:250px;float:left;">
<br>
<b>Teacher's name</b><br><br>
<b>class timing</b><br><br>
<b>Lecture/tutorial</b>
</div>

<div id="content" style="background-color:#CCCCFF;height:500px;width:1000px;float:left;text-align:right;">

<img src="logo.jpg"width="145" height="175">
<table align=center style="width:300px;">
<tr>
  <th style="color:#FF0000;"><i>S.NO</i></th>
  <th style="color:#FF0000;"><i>ENROLLMENT NO.</i></th>
  <th style="color:#FF0000;"><i>NAME</i></th>       
  <th style="color:#FF0000;"><i>PRESENT/ABSENT</i></th>
  </tr>
<tr>
<tr>
  <td>1.</td>
  <td>11102213</td>
  <td>Divyansha</td>        
  <td><form>
<input <?php $myfile = fopen("attendance.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");if(strcmp("Divyansha",fgets($myfile))) echo'checked="checked"';?> type="radio" name="attendance1" value="present">
<input <?php $myfile = fopen("attendance.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!"); if((strcmp("Divyansha",fgets($myfile))==-1)) echo'checked="checked"';?> type="radio" name="attendance1" value="present">
</form></td>
  </tr>
<tr>
  <td>2.</td>
  <td>11102310</td>
  <td>Romil</td>        
  <td> <form>
<input <?php $myfile = fopen("attendance.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");if(strcmp("Romil",fgets($myfile))) echo'checked="checked"';?> type="radio" name="attendance2" value="present">
<input <?php $myfile = fopen("attendance.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");if((strcmp("Romil",fgets($myfile))==-1)) echo'checked="checked"';?> type="radio" name="attendance2" value="present">
</form></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>3.</td>
  <td>11103566</td>
  <td>Shikher</td>      
  <td><form>
<input <?php $myfile = fopen("attendance.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");if(strcmp("Shikher",fgets($myfile))) echo'checked="checked"';?> type="radio" name="attendance1" value="present">
<input <?php $myfile = fopen("attendance.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!"); if((strcmp("Shikher",fgets($myfile))==-1)) echo'checked="checked"';?> type="radio" name="attendance1" value="present">
</form></td>
  </tr>
<tr>
  <td>4.</td>
  <td>11102210</td>
  <td>Dhruv</td>        
  <td><form>
<input <?php $myfile = fopen("attendance.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");if(strcmp("Dhruv",fgets($myfile))) echo'checked="checked"';?> type="radio" name="attendance1" value="present">
<input <?php $myfile = fopen("attendance.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!"); if((strcmp("Dhruv",fgets($myfile))==-1)) echo'checked="checked"';?> type="radio" name="attendance1" value="present">
</form></td>
  </tr>


</table></div>

<div id="footer" style="background-color:#FFA500;clear:both;text-align:center;">
Jaypee Instiute Of Information Technlogy</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

while "attendance.txt" contains:

Romil
Divyansha
Shikher

Comment: Do you use any delimiter in your file to separate each name? It can be anything (, ; . newline or etc)

Comment: yes I am using newline character to separate names...

Comment: Check my below answer hopefully it will help

Comment: it is not helping bro......

Comment: it is still displaying absent for all the names..

Comment: Could you `var_dump` the generated array and see how does it look like?

Comment: dude I got the right code what was wrong in your code was just to use trim() function in the array

Comment: Cool; I hope you just used `fopen` once otherwise multiple calling to the function may lead to performance issues

Answer (score 0):

You can read a file once and create an array of the names and base on that array make the check boxes true or false

```
$names = array();
$handle = @fopen("/path/to/attendance.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (!feof($handle)) {
       $names[] = fgets($handle);
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

**You can also use `file('/path/to/attendance.txt')` function which will return an array corresponds to a line in the file** [File Function Documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php)
Now in your html you can use `in_array`

```
<input <?php if(in_array('Divyansha',$names)) echo'checked="checked"'; ?> type="radio" name="attendance1" value="present">
```